# Alternative to trailing slash in permalink Amazon S3 static site hosting (BitBucket Pipelines and s3_website)

Tags: amazon-s3, jekyll

I'm hosting my static site (built with Jekyll) on Amazon S3. S3 buckets need the URLs to end with `.html`. Since I want clean URLs, I went ahead and added a trailing slash to the `permalink` attribute in my `_config.yml`. Now, my links are like `https://blog.domain.com/2017/07/post-slug/`

This means that each post in the blog would have a separate folder and an `index.html` within it.

What are the **disadvantages** to this approach? Or is there an alternate approach to move-file-and-rename as detailed in [this post](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/jekyll-blog-on-s3-without-html-extension)?

All of my attempts so far at programmatically removing the extension and setting the file type have been unsuccessful because of the setup I'm using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S3 buckets can serve html files that don't end with `.html` if you set the correct MIME type when uploading them.

First, copy the files without extension:

```
aws s3 cp _site/ <your_bucket> --content-type text/html --recursive --exclude "*.*"
```

Then files with .html extension:

```
aws s3 cp _site/ <your_bucket> --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.*"
```

I've been using this method and wrote an article [here](https://simpleit.rocks/having-pretty-urls-in-a-jekyll-website-hosted-in-amazon-s3/) that I think you might find useful.

Comment: Hey @marcanuy, thank you for that! I'm using BitBucket Pipelines to build and deploy the site to S3. `s3_website` pushes the content to S3. I'll try an approach similar to the `aws s3 cp` and revert.

Comment: That worked! I added a step to rename the HTML files as mentioned in your post: `find _site/ -type f ! -iname 'index.html' -iname '*.html' -print0 | while read -d $'\0' f; do mv "$f" "${f%.html}"; done`. While it works without setting the MIME type (for now), I think I should look for a way to explicitly set the MIME type. Thanks a tonne!

Comment: @RamIyer good, I had to explicitly set the file content type or s3 won't recognize it as an html file, may be you can omit that depending on your bucket default configuration.

Comment: I just found out that there's a [YAML config](https://github.com/laurilehmijoki/s3_website/pull/39) that can help with this. I'm using `s3_website` to do the push.

Comment: @RamIyer Nice one, so you can use it with it too, just saw the code and that is the equivalent of `aws`'s `--content-type text/html` parameter for extensionless files.